# Dwellers not giving birth

Tags: fallout-shelter

This is my third day with 2 pregnant dwellers.
I have everything for them to be born nothing has been moved around in my vault, I have space so there should be no problem for them to be born! Not sure if they will ever give birth and I wish I could kill them but they are too scared and run all over the place. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There are about 4 other duplicates of it, too.

Comment: And each duplicate has a couple of "me too"s on it. It's a very popular question, hence why I put a bounty on the original.